# regex script in python or perl

Tags: python, regex, perl

It would really make my work easier if someone could help me with writing script in python or perl in which from given file it retreives all sentences like:

```
[LANG::...]
```

- ... means anything

for ecxample:

```
[LANG::Sample text with digits 0123]
```

and writes it to the fileeach in single line.

Thanks very much for help

EDIT:

Thanks for help, and now something more advanced.

if it finds something like [:ANG:: ...] please write only ... without brackets ang LANG:: tag.

Thanks guys You are awesome :)

Comment: Can  the re be a ] in "anything"? If so, how is it handled? Guess it depends on the data, but it could happen :)

Comment: lets say if someone want to write ] then has to use escape character for example \ so one need to write \]. The same think if someone want to write \ then has to write \\

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import re

with open('input.txt', 'w') as f:
    text = f.read()
#text = 'Intro [LANG::First text 1] goes on [LANG::Second text 2] and finishes.'

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for match in re.findall('\[LANG::.*?\]', text):
        f.write(match+'\n')
```

outputs:

```
[LANG::First text 1]
[LANG::Second text 2]
```

**Second part of the question**: *if it finds something like [:ANG:: ...] please write only ... without brackets and LANG:: tag.*

Change the last part to:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for match in re.findall('\[.ANG::.*?\]', text):
        if match.startswith('[:ANG'):
            f.write(match[7:-1]+'\n')
        else:
            f.write(match+'\n')
```

Fix that substring part `match[7:-1]` to your needs.

Comment: OK could You please tell me how to get text variable value from file not hardcoded string ? thanks

Comment: Well this script doest work if sentence has got for example '-' character. :/

Comment: Why not use `'\[LANG::.*?\]'` or `'\[LANG::[^\]]*\]'`?

Comment: @gruber - then you have to provide enough examples in your question

Comment: I have now changed it to `'\[LANG::.*?\]'` which takes all characters except for (even escaped) `]`.

Comment: Ive edited my question adding second task, Could You look at it ?

Comment: I think `'[:ANG'` is a typo in the OP question it should be `'[LANG'`. You don't need to use slicing on the `match` you could extract necessary part with parentheses http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349783/regex-script-in-python-or-perl/5352563#5352563

Answer (score 4):

perl version

```
perl -lne "print if /\[LANG::.+?\]/;" infile > outfile
```

Comment: Your code retrieves whole lines containing such sentences, not the sentences themselves.

Comment: @eumiro until we see a complete input file my guess is as good as yours

Answer (score 2):

Perl version (edited to get input from file):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $in, '<', 'input.txt');
open(my $out, '>', 'output.txt');

while ( <$in> ) {
    my @found = /\[LANG::.*?\]/g;
    print $out "$_\n" for @found;
}
```

Comment: it could be written simpler in Perl http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349783/regex-script-in-python-or-perl/5352563#5352563

Comment: Simpler is relative. It's indeed shorter, but not suitable if - by any chance - this code is not meant just for a one-liner but has to be incorporated in a bigger script

Answer (score 0):

#### Perl

```
$ perl -nE'say $1 while /\[LANG::([^]]+)\]/g' input.txt >output.txt
```

#### Python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import fileinput, re

for line in fileinput.input():
    for match in re.findall(r'\[LANG::([^]]+)\]', line):
        print match
```

Usage: `$ print-lang input.txt >output.txt`

#### input.txt

```
井の中の蛙、大海を知らず [LANG::Japanese] a frog in a well cannot conceive 
of the ocean [LANG::English]

терпи казак, атаманом будешь [LANG::Russian] no pain, no gain [LANG::English]
```

#### output.txt

```
Japanese
English
Russian
English
```